# Storing user logs on remote server: Which data should be collected in a React Native app?

Tags: react-native, logging

I've developed a react native application where users can login, chose different items from a list, see the details to the item (profile) and add/delete/edit different posts (attached to one item).

Now my user base has grown and therefor I have decided to introduce new database tables in order to log each action my users do to analyze the accumulated data later and optimize for example the usability etc.

**My first question is:** Is there any convention or standard that lists the data to be collected in such a case (like logtime, action, ...)? Don't want to lose any useful data because I've noticed the value of it too late.

**And:** In which time intervals should an app send the users logdata to my remote server (*async requests after each action, daily, before logout...*)? Is there any gold standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it's more about how much data you would like to collect and if it is matching with your privacy terms and conditions. If you're going to store the data on some server other than yours to analyse it, it is highly recommended that you don' refer to user ids there, clearly for privacy reasons.

About when is the right time to log data, again it depends of the data you would like to track, if you are tracking how many minutes they spend on a screen or how they interact with some posts, you may need to send those regularly to your server depending on your needs: whether you want to analyse the data instantly to improve the user experience (show more relevant posts) or just to use the data later. If the data you need to analyse is not really that much, you can do it after each call, if you're planning to track huge amounts of data that you don't need right away, probably you could choose to send the data at time frames where you don't have a big load on your server (to save bandwidth, you can choose night time (it's a little bit more complicated than that))

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailled answer and the suggestion to anonymize the logs. By doing so, we could literally log everything :)

I dont have the intention to track each user. It's more about to see how and which features they prefer/avoid or to check whether the average usage time increases over time and so on.